# How to get parent ID for a commit in a gerrit triggered jenkins pipeline job

Tags: git, jenkins, parent, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

In the pipeline code, I need to retrieve the parent ID for a commit in the jenkins pipeline job triggered by gerrit trigger.

I tried to get the parent ID from the gerrit trigger environment variable $GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION

```
        echo "$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION^"
        echo "${GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}^"
        echo "${env.GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}^"
        echo "$GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION^^"
        echo "${GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}^^"
        echo "${env.GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}^^"
```

Actual result:
SHA1 value of current commit, GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION value followed by 1 or 2 carets ("^")

Expected result:
SHA1 value of parent commit

Jenkins is unable to interpret and escape "^". Any pointers would be of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `git rev-parse` instead of `echo`, supposing in bash:

```
firstparent=$(git rev-parse ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}^)
echo ${firstparent}
```

To successfully retrieve the parent commit, the commit object of the patchset revision must be available from a local git repository. If the snippet runs outside the repository, use `git --git-dir=<path_to_repo_.git> rev-parse ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}^`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointer. It worked after a small change:
firstParent = bat( script: "git rev-parse ${GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION}^^", returnStdout: true)
Was required to escape the caret with another caret.